# How to customize eBay's End of Auction emails?

Tags: email, ebay, customization

As a seller, I'd like to customize eBay's End of Auction email. I couldn't find any up-to-date information about it apart of some old [eBay FAQ page](http://pages.ebay.com/CustomizedEOA/4.html) which says:

> To customize your End of Auction email, go to My eBay:
>
> 1. Click the My eBay button at the top of any page. You may be asked to sign in.
> 2. In the left-hand navigation, click the "eBay Preferences" link under "My Account".
> 3. Under "Seller Preferences", click the "change" link for the "End of Auction and Transaction email".

---

However when I go to Seller Preferences, it reads that the settings has been moved to *Manage communications with buyers* section:

[image: Send customised emails to buyers - Moved to Manage communications with buyers]

---

When following the link, I see some useless page with nothing to change apart of the invoice.

[image: Customising Invoice]

---

Then following the invoice section I cannot upload any logo and the Custom Message box is grayed out as below:

[image: Customising Invoice - Custom Message]

---

Is *Customising Invoice* page the right section to change eBay's End of Auction email? If so, does it mean it cannot be changed until I purchase *eBay Shop* subscription? If it's not the right place, where do I customize eBay's End of Auction emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to eBay specialised department/team, the system is designed in a way that the edit option is not there for customizing afterwards.

So that means it is not possible to customize eBay's End of Auction or End of Transaction emails without purchasing *eBay Shop* subscription and as of now this option is available for the shop owners only. Therefore the mentioned *Custom Message* option in *Customising Invoice* section relates to *Logos and branding* and it is available to *eBay Shops* subscribers only.

It may be possible to customize the message on the PayPal site as mentioned in the [FAQ](http://pages.ebay.com/CustomizedEOA/4.html) page:

> You can also customize your eBay End of Auction email within your Profile section on the PayPal site.

Although it's best to check with PayPal support if there is such option.

Please also note that the mentioned FAQ is referring to US site only and there could be differences in few features for other sites (such as for the UK site).