# How to send custom link to the buyer after purchase?

Tags: paypal, ebay, integration

I've [learned](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102879/22759) that it's not possible to customize eBay's End of Auction or End of Transaction emails without purchasing *eBay Shop* subscription which I'd like to avoid.

However in my auction it's mandatory that I need to send the download link right after each purchase of my software product and I don't want to do it manually after each time.

What would be the alternative way of accomplishing this? Is there any API on eBay or on PayPal side which I can use (like a purchase trigger)?

Comment: PayPal has a lot of documentation about its API. I've coded sites that will automatically perform an action the instant PayPal receives the money from the customer for their purchase on the site. However, I don't know how that would all be set up since the site in question is PayPal. But you could probably find a developer who could create a site for you that would capture the payment trigger and shoot off a customized email to the customer.

Comment: @BrettFromLA I can code myself, just need to some direction which API call is suitable for it or any other approach from somehow you did something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [eBay Platform Notifications](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/Notifications/Notifications.html) which are triggered by events on the eBay site such as such as the ending of a listing, when the buyer has won an auction item ([`ItemWon`](http://ItemWon)) or when the listing had at least one sale ([`ItemSold`](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/Notifications/Notif-ItemSold.html)). You can subscribe to platform notification 
by using [`SetNotificationPreferences`](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/SetNotificationPreferences.html) call which can alert applications and/or users on the given event. The calls can be tested in the Sandbox.

This can be achieved by following steps:

1. Subscribing to Notifications using (`SetNotificationPreferences`).
2. Receiving Notifications (`GetItemTransactions` response).

See: [XML Flow Tutorial: Getting Notifications](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/HowTo/Notifications/Notifications_listing.html) for further details.

> [eBay Developers Program](http://developer.ebay.com/join) membership is free, and you can use virtually any programming language to interface with eBay Web Services. See: [What is the eBay API?](https://go.developer.ebay.com/what-ebay-api)